# What is the error covariance structure for linear mixed effects models estimated by lme4?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Recently I read a lot about error covariance structures, especially for longitudinal models. I have found that it is not possible to specify such a structure in `lme4`. So my question is, what kind of structure does it assume/estimate ? It seems that it's something like $\delta I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\delta$ is the (scalar) error variance which is estimated and shown as part of the random effects output of `lme4:::summary.merMod`.

Is this correct and, if so, does this structure have any name ?

Comment: This seems like a major disadvantage of R compared to SAS, which offers a large variety of choices. But I wonder if there is a work around.

Comment: @PeterFlom This is a limitation of the `lme4` package, not of $\textsf{R}$. Other package, such as `nlme`, implement R-side effects or covariance structures.

Comment: @statmerkur That makes sense and is good to know.  I've retired, but when I was working, I mostly used SAS.  These days, I don't have access to it (it's expensive) and my R knowledge is somewhat lacking.

Comment: @PeterFlom I have also read that by fitting random slopes for the time variable, this results in something similar to an AR1 structure. I have probably got that wrong (AR1 that is), I'm not entirely sure what exactly it does do (that was going to be the subject of a further question. I just didn't want to ask too much in one go!)

Comment: I've seen conflicting information but always assumed `lme4` did unstructured only. [This](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/varmats.html) page shows how you can trick it into fitting certain structured covariances - never tried though & looks complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You can, e.g., read this off from the conditional distribution of the response given the random effects shown in expression $(2)$ in [this `lme4` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/Theory.pdf). Such an error distribution is called "spherical".

---

**Addendum**

`lme4` can fit linear mixed models obeying measurement models of the form
$$
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}} = \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol \beta + \boldsymbol Z \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} + \boldsymbol o + \boldsymbol \epsilon,
$$
with response vector $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}} \in \mathbb R^n$, fixed-effects design matrix $\boldsymbol X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$, fixed-effects parameter vector $\boldsymbol \beta \in \mathbb R^p$, random-effects design matrix $\boldsymbol Z \in \mathbb R^{n \times q}$, random-effects vector $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} \in \mathbb R^q$, (known) offset vector $\boldsymbol o \in \mathbb R^n$, error vector $\boldsymbol \epsilon \in \mathbb R^n$;
and the distributional assumption
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}\\
\boldsymbol \epsilon
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\mathop{\mathcal N_{q + n}}
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol \Sigma_{\boldsymbol \theta} & \mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0 & \sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n
\end{pmatrix}
\right),
$$
with positive semi-definite covariance matrix $\boldsymbol \Sigma_{\boldsymbol \theta} \in \mathbb R^{q \times q}$ parameterized by the covariance parameter vector $\boldsymbol \theta \in \mathbb R^m$.

Such linear mixed models can also be written in the hierarchical form
$$
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}} \,|\, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = \boldsymbol b
\sim 
\mathop{\mathcal N_n}
\left(
\boldsymbol X \boldsymbol \beta + \boldsymbol Z \boldsymbol b + \boldsymbol o, 
\sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n
\right), \\
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}
\sim
\mathop{\mathcal N_q}
\left(
\mathbf 0,
\boldsymbol \Sigma_{\boldsymbol \theta}
\right),
$$
which is the form used in the [`lme4` vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/).

From this we can see that the implied distribution of the error vector $\boldsymbol \epsilon$ is $\mathop{\mathcal N_n}\left(\mathbf 0, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol I_n\right)$, a spherical multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Does this then mean that we should be checking our data for sphericity before running lmer?

Comment: @HarD I'm not so sure. What would you check ? It's the *residuals* that have this covariance structure, so how can you obtain the residuals before fitting the model ? Perhaps/hopefully statmerkur will comment

Comment: @statmerkur do you have any comment on HarD's comment ? If we did want to test the residuals, can we, for example, look at a histogram for ALL the residuals lumped together, or do we have to look individually at each subject's residuals ? In the case of lme4 we have only a single estimate for the residual variance, so my guess is that we *can* look at all the residuals. Is that right ? What about the case with other software that allows heterogeneous variances across subjects - if we lumped all the residuals together and looked at histograms/QQ plots etc, would that be a mistake ?

Comment: @HardD Not necessarily. Sphericity is an assumption that usually concerns the *marginal* (w.r.t. the random effects) *covariance matrix* of "subvectors" (corresponding to levels of a grouping factor, e.g., individuals) of the response. And it's possible to specify `lmer` models whose random effects imply marginal covariance matrices that are more flexible than sphericity.

Comment: @Harmony Technically it's not the residuals but the errors that have a spherical covariance matrix. One approach to residual analysis in linear mixed models is to (1) calculated the estimated marginal covariance matrix of the response $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}}$, (2) generate the transformed residuals $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{Y}}}^{-1/2}\left(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol X \hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)$, (3) apply residual diagnostics for the classical linear regression model to these transformed residuals.

Answer (score 8):

The older [**nlme**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nlme) allows to specify various structures for the error terms via its `correlation` and `weights` arguments; check the online help file [corClasses](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/corClasses.html) to see what's available.

The [**lme4**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4) allows only to model the correlations in the data using random effects. In **lme4** you may also use observation-level random effects to allow more flexibility in modeling the error terms. You may find some information in the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html).